# Github Graph: to show added line of only specific files

Tags: git, github

Github has this neat feature of showing commit stats in Github Graph. One of the graphs shows number of lines committed during a specific period. Unfortunately, I'm having this problem that some data files were committed with huge number of lines which is also included in stats. But I don't want to show them in the stats: i only want the number of lines for .java files. Is that possible?

Comment: Shouo, don't forget to mark Ivan's answer. He works at GitHub so he knows what is possible and what is not. `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not possible currently. As you said, GitHub counts what it can since it really can't know what makes sense for each repo in particular (it might make sense to count for some repos, and for others it might make sense not to).